# TableView backgroundColor not changing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, background-color

I have a grouped tableView, and I am trying to change the default background to custom color. I have looked all over, and the closest thing to working is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:181 green:293 blue:223 alpha:0];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

This code changes the background to white, but I can't get it to change to the custom color. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating the color incorrectly. The RGBA values need to be in the range 0.0 - 1.0. `UIColor` will treat anything over 1.0 as 1.0. So your color is being set to white since all three RGB values will be treated as 1.0. Also note that an alpha of 0 means totally transparent. You want 1.0 to mean totally visible.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:181/255.0 green:293/255.0 blue:223/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}
```

Please note that your green value is 293. That needs to be changed to something from 0 to 255.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this code isn't working. The background is still white.

Comment: The alpha should be 1.0, not 0.0.

Answer (score 3):

Your RGBA values should be 0.0 - 1.0.

**Make sure alpha value should not be 0.0, to see the colour effect**

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:1.0 blue:0.85 alpha:1.0];
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```